# C# why isnt setting one object equal to another working?

Tags: c#, object, properties

I have a piece of code where I want to switch database connections used with my Dapper queries.

It is pretty simple but when I set my connection object equal to anther one it is not actually working.  The connection string either side of the operation stays the same.

I suspect this has nothing to do with Dapper, or the database connection but is something more fundamental.  The code is not my own but something I have picked up.

I have run out of ideas to debug why this might be happening.  Any ideas of what I can look for?

I have frozen all other threads to make sure that nothing else could be modifying the connection object behind the scenes.

This is the code I am running:

```
    void SetConnection(){
      if (Db.Diablo.Connection?.Name != Connection.ConnectionId)
      {
        ConnectionInfo conInfo = Connection.GetSqlConnectionInfo;
        Console.WriteLine($"Previous DB.Diablo.Connection = {Db.Diablo.Connection.ConnectionString}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Required DB.Diablo.Connection = {conInfo.ConnectionString}");
        Db.Diablo.Connection = conInfo;
        Console.WriteLine($"New DB.Diablo.Connection = {Db.Diablo.Connection.ConnectionString}");
      }
    }
```

Which gives this output:

```
Previous DB.Diablo.Connection = data source = localhost\sqlexp_2008r2; initial catalog = Diablo_Demo_A; integrated security = true
Required DB.Diablo.Connection = data source = localhost\sqlexp_2008r2; initial catalog = Diablo_Demo_B; integrated security = true
New DB.Diablo.Connection = data source = localhost\sqlexp_2008r2; initial catalog = Diablo_Demo_A; integrated security = true
```

So clearly it isn't changing.

Connection info is a simple get/set property of the DapperQuery object:

```
    public ConnectionInfo Connection{
      get;
      set;
    }
```

I could post all the object definitions, but would be a lot to trawl though.  if it would help i would be happy to though!

Thank you.

Update: Here is code for the ConnectionInfo type:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using JetBrains.Annotations;


// ReSharper disable MemberCanBePrivate.Global


namespace AmFunctions.Sql{
  [Serializable] public class ConnectionInfo{
    #region  Constructors
    public ConnectionInfo(string filename, [NotNull] string password, DbType type, int version){
      DatabaseFileName = filename;
      DatabaseType = type;
      Password = password;
      Version = version;
      UpdateConnectionString();
    }

    public ConnectionInfo(string dataSource, string initialCatalog, DbType databaseType, string userId = "", [NotNull] string password = ""){
      InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;
      DataSource = dataSource;
      UserId = userId;
      Password = password;
      DatabaseType = databaseType;
      UpdateConnectionString();
    }

    public ConnectionInfo(string connectionString, DbType databaseType){
      CustomConnectionString = connectionString;
      IsCustomConnectionString = true;
      DatabaseType = databaseType;
      UpdateConnectionString();
    }
    #endregion


    #region  Constructors
    ConnectionInfo(){ }
    #endregion


    #region  Public Delegates and Enums
    public enum DbType{ SqlCe, SqlLite, SqlServer, NotSet }
    #endregion


    #region Class Variables
    string _encryption_key;
    string _stored_password;
    bool _use_integrated_security;
    #endregion


    #region Properties
    public bool IsCustomConnectionString{ get; set; }
    public bool UseIntegratedSecurity{
      get => _use_integrated_security;
      set{
        _use_integrated_security = value;
        UpdateConnectionString();
      }
    }

    bool WindowsSecurity => UseIntegratedSecurity || UserId.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() || Password.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();
    public DbType DatabaseType{ get; set;}
    public int Version{ get; set; }
    [NotNull] public string ConnectionString => GetConnectionString(InitialCatalog);
    public string CustomConnectionString{ get; set; }
    public string DatabaseFileName{ get; set; }
    public string DataSource{ get; set; }
    public string InitialCatalog{ get; set; }
    [NotNull] public string MasterConnectionString => GetConnectionString("Master");
    [NotNull] public string Password{ get => Encryption.Decrypt(_stored_password, _encryption_key); set => _stored_password = Encryption.Encrypt(value, _encryption_key); }
    public string UserId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
    public bool CanTest =>(IsCustomConnectionString && CustomConnectionString.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace()) || (CanTestMaster && !InitialCatalog.IsNullOrWhiteSpace());
    public bool CanTestMaster=> !DataSource.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();
    public bool TestConnection(bool throwExceptionIfNot = true,bool testConnectionToServerOnly = false)
    {
      switch (DatabaseType) {
        case DbType.SqlCe:
          return true;
        case DbType.SqlLite: return true;
        case DbType.SqlServer:
          return TestOk_sql(throwExceptionIfNot,testConnectionToServerOnly);
        case DbType.NotSet: return false;
        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
      }
    }

    bool TestOk_sql(bool throwExceptionIfNot,bool testConnectionToServerOnly ){
      string connectionString = testConnectionToServerOnly ? MasterConnectionString : ConnectionString;
      try
      {
        using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionString + ";connection timeout = 2"))
        {
          //Try and open it
          db.Open();
          db.Close();
          return true;
        }

      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        if (throwExceptionIfNot) throw;

        return false;
      }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Methods
    public void SetEncryptionKey(string key){
      _stored_password = Password;
      _encryption_key = key;
      Password = _stored_password;
    }

    public void SetPassword(string password, string encryptionKey){
      _stored_password = password;
      _encryption_key = "";
      SetEncryptionKey(encryptionKey);
    }

    void UpdateConnectionString(){
      //if(IsCustomConnectionString) return; 

      switch(DatabaseType){
        case DbType.SqlCe:
          CustomConnectionString = "Data Source='%server%'" + "; LCId=1033; Password=%password%;" + " Encrypt = TRUE; Case Sensitive = FALSE";
          break;
        case DbType.SqlLite:
          string password = Password.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? "" : "Password = %password%; ";
          CustomConnectionString = $"Data Source = {DatabaseFileName}; Version = {Version}; {password}Pooling=True; Max Pool Size=100";
          break;
        case DbType.SqlServer:
          string securityString = WindowsSecurity ? "integrated security = true" : "user id = %username%; password = %password%";
          CustomConnectionString = $"data source = %server%; initial catalog = %database%; {securityString}";
          break;
        default:
          CustomConnectionString = "";
          break;
      }


    }

    [NotNull]
    string GetConnectionString(string initialCatalog){
      if(CustomConnectionString==null) UpdateConnectionString();
      return CustomConnectionString?.Replace("%server%", DataSource)
                                   .Replace("%database%", initialCatalog)
                                   .Replace("%username%", UserId)
                                   .Replace("%password%", Password) ??
        "";
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the getter for `Connection.ConnectionString`? Is it just a plain string or is it a special property?

Comment: Is ConnectionInfo a singleton? Maybe post the code for that object.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft  code up now.  Its not a singleton.

Comment: @user1538301 Code posted.  It is a special property.  Thank you!